# PHP: Reassign array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key, natsort

I have an array of numbers from descending order. When I add to this array, I add to the end and then do `natsort($times)`. $times then looks like this (obtained by print_r):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.01
    [1] => 0.02
    [2] => 0.05
    [3] => 0.08
    [7] => 0.10   <-- Just added and natsorted
    [4] => 0.11
    [5] => 0.14
    [6] => 0.21
)
```

However, I wish to reassign all the keys so that the just-added 0.10 is array index 4 making it easy to see what place the new time is in. ie "your ranking is $arrayindex+1"

Besides copying this whole array into a new array to get new keys, is there a better way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`sort` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with `SORT_NUMERIC`, instead of `natsort`:

```
sort($times, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Unlike `natsort`, it re-indexes the array.

---

<del>There is no built in way to re-index the array after/while sorting.</del> You could also use [`array_values` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) after sorting with `natsort`:

```
$times = array_values($times);
```

This *is* copying the array though.

Comment: Why should he? Is this faster?

Comment: @Jitamaro: What do you mean? I mean he should use `sort` instead of `natsort`. This will be faster (well, depends on what `array_values` is doing under the hood, but it is likely that calling only one method is faster than calling two).

Comment: `sort($times, SORT_NUMERIC);` worked perfectly for me as an alternative to natsort

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with array_values.

```
$times=array_values($times);
```

Answer (score 2):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) reassigns array keys after sorting, use it with [strnatcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```
usort( $times, 'strnatcmp' );
```